# Выборка из 2х таблиц по разным id

Tags: выборка, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы, из нужно тянуть все данные, НО по order by каждой таблицы id <br>
пробовал так:

```
SELECT id_post AS union_id, * FROM post
UNION ALL
SELECT id_quote AS union_id, * FROM quote
ORDER BY union_id DESC
```

Выдает ошибку:

Unknown column 'union_id' in 'order clause'

Comment: количество полей проверьте в обоих запросах - должно быть одинаковым. и, да, * не используйте, она помогает только в консоли когда надо посмотреть быстро таблицу. в остальных случаях всегда надо писать список полей, сэкономите себе время на исправлениях и поисках ошибок.

Comment: Во второй таблице меньше полей, как быть?

Comment: чет ты не правильно делаешь, но можешь добавить в select 1, 1...

Comment: Немного не понял

Comment: добавь единицы до нужного кол-ва полей

Comment: по смыслу лучше null, а не 1. А еще лучше в таком случае сделать два запроса.

Comment: 2 запроса не выйдет, мне под пагинатор в 1 запрос надо.

Answer (score 1):

Да, [@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets) прав. Нужна структура ваших данных. По названиям таблиц и * нельзя понять что у вас там хранится и что в итоге вы хотите получить одним запросом.

Предположим, что вас интересуют все посты и комментарии к этим постам в едином списке.
И, скажем, в список надо вывести ссылку по на пост/комментарий, автора, дату, возможно тему...

Заметьте, список полей, которые надо получить, формируете заранее и все их перечисляете в запросе, а те поля, которые не нужны, не упоминать. Если для одной таблицы поле из другой смысла не имеет, то вместо этого поля пишете значение, например `NULL`. Получится что-то типа:

```
select 'post' as source, id_post as union_id, author, post_date as _date, title
from posts
union all
select 'quote' as source, id_quote, commenter, comment_date, NULL
from quotes
order by union_id;
```

Запрос вернет ваш список. В зависимости от поля source в результате, вы будете знать к какой таблице будет относиться `id` - к `posts` или `quotes`, ведь они могут совпадать...

**N.B.** При использовании `union all` псевдонимы для полей выборки достаточно задать для первой таблицы, объединение будет идти по порядку полей, а не по названиям, именно поэтому * в запросе может только навредить, вдруг структура изменится.

см. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b951/6) с примером разных запросов...

ЗЫ Гораздо проще было бы помочь, если бы вопрос был задан более точно и полно.

Answer (score -1):

Вот что соорудил, но как тут быть, писать все колонки которые ест ьв таблице? если кол. не совпадает.

```
SELECT F.*, S.* FROM post F, quote S ORDER BY F.id_post DESC, S.id_quote DESC
```

Comment: ты не правильно делаешь, пишу 2й раз, какая у тебя архитектура таблиц? а таблицы с комментами есть поле с ид статьи? надо сделать джойн на эту таблицу